# Infinite for loop with nested while loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

I keep getting an issue with an infinite loop in both the FOR and WHILE loop. I am trying to nest a while loop that will stop running when the number given by allNum[i] reaches 1. I get an error that both my for and while loops have an infinite loop issue. I'm still learning how to use loops, I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```js
let numbers = []

//create a loop to iterate through the numbers array
for (let i = 0, n = allNum.length; i < n; i++) {

  //create a new variable to store sub arrays
  let subArr = [];

  //use a while to stop when the number is divided down to 1 and then store divisors in an array if (allNum[i] % n == 0) if true allNum[i]/n and subArr.push(n); if false n++

  while (allNum[i] > 0) {
    let c = 2;

    //if true then divide the number by n and add the n (divisor) to subArr, in this case we have to try the same number again to divide by the new value of i so don't increase n

    if (allNum[i] % c == 0) {
      allNum[i] = allNum[i] / c;
      subArr.push(c);

      //if false then make n go up by 1 number
    } else {
      c++;
    }

  } //WHILE ENDS

  numbers.push(subArr);
  console.log(allNum[i]) //using for testing only
} //FOR ENDS

console.log(numbers, '<- divisors & array ->', allNum); //using for testing only
return numbers;
}
```

Comment: Imagine what happens if `allNums[i] === 1`  You start with `c = 2`. So `allNums[i] % c` can never be `0`. But while `allNums[i] != 0` you are just increasing `c` and not modifying `allNums[i]`. Thus, the `while`loop will never end.

Comment: There's no function definition, what is `return numbers` returning from?

Comment: "stop running when the number given by allNum[i] reaches 1." Your loop stops running when it becomes 0 or negative.

Comment: `allNum[i] = allNum[i] / c` will never cause `allNum[i]` to be 0 because `allNums[i]` is a multiple of `c`.

Comment: Also you are setting `c = 2` in the first statment of EVERY iteration of the while loop. So the increment `c++` later on does not have any effect anymore, once the next iteration of the loop starts ... Ie, your `c` will never become greater than `2`. You should probalby move the `let c = 2` before the while loop